# Throwing Exception in CTOR and Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, constructor, smart-pointers, raii

Is it OK to have the following code in my constructor to load an XML document into a member variable - throwing to caller if there are any problems:

```
   MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr m_docPtr; //member


Configuration()
{
    try
    {                      
        HRESULT hr = m_docPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument40));     

         if ( SUCCEEDED(hr))
         {
            m_docPtr->loadXML(CreateXML());
         }
         else
         {
            throw MyException("Could not create instance of Dom");
          }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
         LogError("Exception when loading xml");
         throw;
    }

}
```

Based on Scott Myers RAII implementations in More Effective C++ he cleanups if he alocates any resources i.e. pointers:

```
BookEntry::BookEntry(const string& name,
                 const string& address,
                 const string& imageFileName,
                 const string& audioClipFileName)
: theName(name), theAddress(address),
  theImage(0), theAudioClip(0)
{
  try {                            // this try block is new
    if (imageFileName != "") {
      theImage = new Image(imageFileName);
    }

  if (audioClipFileName != "") {
      theAudioClip = new AudioClip(audioClipFileName);
    }
  }
  catch (...) {                      // catch any exception


    delete theImage;                 // perform necessary
    delete theAudioClip;             // cleanup actions


    throw;                           // propagate the exception
  }
}
```

I believe I am alright in just allowing exceptions to be thrown from CTOR as I am using a smart pointer(IXMLDOMDocumentPtr).

Let me know what you think....

Comment: Why the `try { ... } ... catch(...) {}` ?  Can fix the code so that it actually looks like a constructor definition, otherwise it's a bit difficult to give constructive criticism.

Comment: I do not understand you problem. It is generally OK to throw exceptions from constructors. What is your concern? What alternatives do you consider?

Comment: You are worried about whether the `m_docPtr` variable gets destructed or not when you throw exception?

Comment: What are your concerns? What negative consequences do you suspect?

Comment: The code that you've attributed to Scott Meyers is an illustrative example from half way through Item 10 of MEC++. You should carry on reading to the end of Item 10 where he presents a much simpler and more robust solution using `const auto_ptr` .

Comment: @Charles Yep - I have.  I'm assuming that the fact that IXMLDOMDocumentPtr is a smart pointer means I am in the same situation.  COM == Doubt!

Comment: @David Relihan: COM has nothing to add here. A smart pointer is yet another class and is treated like yet another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ guarantees that in case of an exception all fully constructed objects will be destroyed.

Since `m_docPtr` is a member of `class Configuration` it will have been fully constructed before the `class Configuration` constructor body begins, so if you throw an exception from `class Configuration` body as you intended in your first snippet `m_docPtr` will be destroyed.

Comment: Does the fact I'm calling creatingInstance effect this?

Comment: No, the destructor of `m_docPtr` will be called unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to do anything in the catch block? If nothing, you probably do not need the try catch. On windows, I believe that catch(...) catches hardware interrupts (experts please correct), something to keep in mind.